# Does the limit of the sum equal the sum of the limits in this case?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

I'm interested in evaluating the following limit:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n= 1}^N\frac{1}{N\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{N}\right)}
\end{align*}
Because 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{N}\right)} &= \frac{1}{\pi n}
\end{align*}
is the following reasoning justified?
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^N\frac{1}{N\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{N}\right)} &= \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2\pi} + \frac{1}{3\pi} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\pi N} \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi}\left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{N}\right) \\
&= \text{DNE}
\end{align*}
In general, is there a more systematic way to evaluate such limits? I'm unaccustomed to seeing the upper limit of summation appear in the expression itself.

Comment: Looks like a Riemann sum in disguise.

Comment: To prove the limit is infinite, simply use $\sin(\pi x)\leqslant\pi x$ for every nonnegative $x$ and deduce that $$\sum_{n= 1}^N\frac{1}{N\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{N}\right)}\geqslant\sum_{n= 1}^{N}\frac{1}{\pi n}\to\infty.$$

Comment: @WhiteShirt Riemann sums are for continuous (hence bounded) functions.

Comment: Indeed, though OP's observation "seeing the upper limit of summation appear in the expression itself" reminded me of the formula

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f\left (\frac{n}{N}\right )=\int_0^1 f\left (x\right ) \mathrm{d}x$$

In this case $f(x)=1/\sin(\pi x)$. Of course, the integral does not converge in $[0,1]$, so neither would the limit.